# Selenium WebDriver Get method

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning Python with "Automate the boring stuff with Python" by Al Sweigart. Currently, I'm stuck with the Selenium web driver. The Selenium web driver can open a firefox window, but the method `get` does not open the URL `http://google.com/`. I've searched about this problem on the net, but I did not find any helpful answers. Help?

Comment: Please share your code trials

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I made some minor edits to your language and formatting. Please provide the specific code you're using and any specific error messages you're seeing, otherwise it's difficult for us to figure out how to help you.

Comment: Hi Claus. Yeah, I should have explained more. So, I'm using PyCharm, Selenium 3.8 and latest version of Firefox.

This is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

(I'm new here so I don't know better way to show my code)


So, my code opens firefox browser, but did not execute GET and won't show my url. I hope I explained right.

Answer (score 0):

Please try including the complete url -

```
browser.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: My bad, i did not show it like it is. I've been using the complete url, and still, have problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while we initiate the webdriver we need to pass the absolute path of the Geckodriver as follows :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
```

Finally, per best programming practices while invoking **`get()`** method, we must mention the **`Protocol`** and the **`www`** part both. So the ideal line of code will be :

```
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```